# Upgrade of Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I am running Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 4. The OS shows "Ubuntu 13.10(r101)". At what time will I be able to upgrade to 14.04, i mean "over the air"? Or how can I upgrade now without loosing my data (music, contacts)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to 'switch' (see Install page), but I would recommend doing a fresh install of Trusty (14.04) beta. If you are trying to keep all data, then you need to backup (and not rely on conversion).

[wiki.ubuntu > Touch > Instructions for flashing phone/tablet](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

---

I have the **new** 14.04 beta (build 209), *based on **AOSP 4.4.2** source code*, running on my **Nexus 4**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your phone with your ubuntu PC through USB
2. [Read this for the necessary packages you need on your PC](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)
3. Open terminal in your PC
4. Type `sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=trusty`. If you would like the version in development (14.10) type `sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/devel`